# Data js em html(script externo)

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho o seguinte script que retorna data e hora:

```
function RetornaDataHoraAtual(){
    var dNow = new Date();
    var localdate = dNow.getDate() + '/' + (dNow.getMonth()+1) + '/' + dNow.getFullYear() + ' ' + dNow.getHours() + ':' + dNow.getMinutes();
    return localdate;
 }
```

E uma página html(a seguir) de onde eu o chamo, nesse trecho de código(que, quando executo, nada acontece - nenhuma saída é exibida). Onde posso estar errando?

```
<div class="container">
  <label>Cronômetro de Monitoramento, até a data de  <script src="retornaData.js"></script> </label>
    <?!= include("grafico"); ?>
    <font size="1" face="Verdana"><i><b>Nota:</b> Apenas monitoramentos concluídos(no prazo e fora do prazo) e empacados. </i><u>Excluem-se os que estão em andamento.</u></i></fonte>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
```

Comment: Se não me engano, é necessário inicializar a função: 'nomeFuncao()', ao que parece você está apenas declarando a função dentro do script, falta apertar o play. Posso estar enganado.

Comment: Mas quando eu chamo a função, dentro dela, eu já tenho o return, que retorna a variavel que armazena a data.

Comment: O correto é após a declaração, não?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que essa não é a melhor forma para utilizar essa sua função.
Você pode utilizar as opções de **document.getElementById** para capturar o elemento onde você quer deixar seu texto, o **document.createTextNode** para criar o elemento do texto e o **appendChild** para prende-lo no elemento escolhido.

(Você pode colocar o javascript externo, estou apenas demonstrando no meio do código)

Segue o exemplo a seguir:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <label>Cronômetro de Monitoramento, até a data de  <span id="data"></span></label>
    <?!= include("grafico"); ?>
    <font size="1" face="Verdana"><i><b>Nota:</b> Apenas monitoramentos concluídos(no prazo e fora do prazo) e empacados. </i><u>Excluem-se os que estão em andamento.</u></i></fonte>
  </div>

  <div class="row">


<script>

let data = document.getElementById('data');
var text = document.createTextNode(RetornaDataHoraAtual());        
data.appendChild(text);

function RetornaDataHoraAtual(){
    var dNow = new Date();
    var localdate = dNow.getDate() + '/' + (dNow.getMonth()+1) + '/' + dNow.getFullYear() + ' ' + dNow.getHours() + ':' + dNow.getMinutes();
    return localdate;
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Caso ainda houver dúvidas, estou a disposição para te ajudar!

Comment: Deu certo. Porém, não executa se o script estiver externo. Não entendi. Mas da forma que está no código está exibindo como eu quero.

Comment: Roger, tudo bem?
Você está inserindo o arquivo externo pela tag? Seria assim:
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nome-do-arquivo-externo.js"></script>

Comment: Oi, vou deixar do jeito que está, no código mesmo. Muito obrigado.